# Extensions for Doctrine ORM

Tags: symfony1, doctrine

I'm working on a PHP project and evaluating Symfony 2 + Doctrine ORM. Coming back to PHP from Ruby on Rails, I'm wondering if there are parallels for the `acts_as`-style [ActiveRecord plugins](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=acts_as) that are available all over GitHub for common behaviours in Rails.

Doctrine itself only has a few standard extensions for [Translatable](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-behavioral-extensions#translatable), [Tree](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-behavioral-extensions#tree), [Sluggable](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-behavioral-extensions#sluggable), and [Timestampable](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine2-behavioral-extensions#timestampable). I was able to find a few other items on GitHub.

I'm looking for things like sortable lists, some implementation of soft-delete, state machines, file attachments (images), and so on. Is anything similar available or is it a roll-your-own ecosystem? Where can I find more resources?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions, there's some awesome extensions!